# How do I view multiple posts on WP REST API?

Tags: wordpress, jetpack, wp-api

I can do `https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/www.website.com/posts/` to view the latest 20 posts on a WP site.

How do I view more than 20? Or view all the posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [documentation for `GET /sites/$site/posts/`](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1.1/get/sites/%24site/posts/), just include the appropriate `number` and `page` paramenters in a query string.

To view the first 100:

https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/en.blog.wordpress.com/posts/?number=100&page=1

To view the second 100:

https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/en.blog.wordpress.com/posts/?number=100&page=2

etc.

Comment: Ah, didn't find that documentation. Thanks! It works perfectly.